# Complicated text extract

Tags: excel, find, extract

I have this text in cell A1:

> Age risk: Very low Location risk: Very high

I want to find the text between the first colon (":") and the 2nd space to the left of the 2nd colon.  The cell contents can change significantly, but using this logic should always capture the necessary text.  In this particular case, I'm trying to isolate "Very Low"

I can find the positions of the colons (":")

- 1st =FIND(":",A1) -- position 9
- 2nd =FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)  -- position 33

But, I can't figure out how to count back two spaces to the left of the 2nd colon to be able to use it in a MID.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,(location of 2nd space to left of 2nd colon -FIND(":",A1)))
```

Comment: Can you please post some more examples of the input and output? From what I know, you may also have `Age risk: high Address number: 123` and you want `high`. From `Word word: very very high indeed Word Word: word word word`, you want `very very high indeed`, etc. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a complicated formula, but much simpler using a UDF and Regular Expressions.  The following UDF

- Removes everything up to and including any spaces following the first colon
- it then captures everything after that until, by looking forward, it can a sequence of
- it then removes everything after that point.

One advantage of this is that it is more easily modified if you find the description doesn't always match.

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractSpecial(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "^[^:]+:\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\S+\s+\S+:).*"
    .MultiLine = True
    ExtractSpecial = .Replace(S, "$1")
End With

End Function
```

**EDIT** Explanation of Regex Pattern with links to further explanations:

### ^[^:]+:\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\S+\s+\S+:).*

```
^[^:]+:\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\S+\s+\S+:).*
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match any character that is NOT the colon character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^:]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the colon character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(.*?)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*?`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\s+\S+\s+\S+:)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the colon character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$1

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: I was thinking UDF might be better, as I'm working toward a formula solution but it's getting pretty hairy pretty quick...`Mid()` with some `Substitute()` and `Len()`, and `Search()` ...

Comment: That seems to be working.  Can you please help translate the pattern?

Comment: @acsql I have added a formal explanation of the regex pattern, with links to more details. Please ask if you have any more questions about this method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll always have "location" in there too, you can search for that, and trim it down:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,SEARCH("location",A1)-SEARCH(":",A1)-1))`

Edit: Per your comment:

`=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,SEARCH(";",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",";",4))-SEARCH(":",A1)))`

Comment: Thanks, but "location" won't always be found.  It's always a 2 word phrase,  but the words themselves can't be predicted, which is why I thought using 
the 2nd space to the left of the 2nd colon would be the only option.

Comment: @acsql - See my edit. Will that work? Or might you have multiple words? I used the assumption that after the fourth space, you want to trim that off.  Edit: Hm, give me a second. As noted in the other answer, you might have "Age risk: high", in which case this won't work.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't know if it is relevant, but if there are more than two words to be returned, your formula only returns the first two words.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand all of the spaces to repeated spaces that are the length of the original you can pick and choose which portion of the original text to parse out.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(32), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), (B2-1)*LEN(A2)+1, C2*LEN(A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Woah! So, with this, I think OP wants: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(32), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A2))), (B2-1)*LEN(A2)+1, C2*LEN(A2)))`.  I have been sitting here doing way to much mental gymnastics trying to figure it out with a formula. Well done Jeeped!

Comment: TBPH @BruceWayne, despite reading and rereading this question several times, I'm unclear on **exactly** what the OP wants to accomplish so I formulated my response to accommodate various scenarios.